# Cheap hosting for php+mongodb app

Tags: php, mongodb, hosting, web-hosting

I built a small app for myself but now I'd like to host it somewhere for others to use too.

Is there any cheap options to host php+mongo stack without renting an expensive VPS?

Comment: Renting an inexpensive VPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best best would require you to still roll your own server and set it up. But the two hosting services that come to mind are Linode and Digital Ocean.

https://www.linode.com/

https://www.digitalocean.com/

I have used both and they can be very affordable. The downside is that you have to do your own setup and config. They do provide lots of tools to help out with that. Scripts you can run and pre-made images.